# How to add a CCK field-type in a form?

Tags: php, drupal-6, menu, cck

Hi I'm having the following issue (or misunderstanding): I'm registering a path (using hook_menu in a custom module), let's say the path is `admin/some_settings`. On this page I'm supposed to show a form with some file (images) upload fields.

I know how to this with standard field-types from Drupal but I want to add some CCK field-types (again they will be images). The reason for using CCK field types is I want to impose restrictions (file types, size, resolution etc.).

I also know how to do this with CCK for a content type but I don't know hot to do it for a registered menu. So any ideas or resources (just for the record: I've been using Drupal for 2 weeks so bear with me)?

Update: I think i found a solution now I only need an example. The solution is to find a module that has in the settings form a field that looks like something I'm looking for. Then I only need to look at the implementation. If anyone knows amodule that has an upload image field (imagefield preferably) in the settings menu  let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible in Drupal-6. CCK fields were built to be attached to nodes. But thanks to the new Drupal-7 fields and entities things are easier now.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that you then pose with your answer...I am looking for that way to do it in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

http://groups.drupal.org/node/16542

http://coder1.com/articles/adding-cck-field-to-custom-form

Hope this gives you a starting point.

Comment: Thx for the links. The second one I've already read it, but again they start from a CCK field that is defined in a content type. The other one also seems to start from the same premises: They all revolve around this function content_fields which gets a field from a content type... Seems there is no other way... I still feel I'm missing something in order to fully understand this, not sure what it is though.